# Existence of solution to Fredholm integral equation of the second kind under a condition on the spectral radius

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, integral-equations

Consider the Fredholm integral equation of the second kind given by
$$
f(x)=g(x)+\int_a^bk(x,y)f(y)\ \mathrm dy.
$$
In any source I could find online, including some more advanced ones, existence of solutions (and also, uniqueness, and continuous dependence on initial conditions) is proven under conditions like $\|k\|_{\infty}< 1$ or $\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\int_a^b|k(x,y)|\ \mathrm dy<1$. In the textbook *Volterrra Integral and Functional equations* by Gripenberg, Londen and Steffans, when working on $L^p[a,b]$, this is proven (pages 227 and 235) under the condition that
$$
\|k\|_{p}:=\sup_{\substack{\phi\in L^q[a,b]\\\psi\in L^p[a,b]}}\int_a^b\int_a^b|\phi(x)k(x,y)\psi(y)|\ \mathrm dx\ \mathrm dy<1,
$$
where $p $ and $q$ are conjugate, i.e. $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. I intend to work on $L^1[a,b]$, with a positive kernel $k$, in which case the condition simplifies to
$$
\sup_{\psi\in L^1[a,b]}\int_a^b\int_a^b|k(x,y)\psi(y)|\ \mathrm dx\ \mathrm dy<1,
$$
i.e. the operator norm $\|T\|_{op}$ of $$T:L^1[a,b]\to L^1[a,b]:f(\cdot)\mapsto \int_a^bk(\cdot,y)f(y)\ \mathrm dy$$ should be bounded by $1$.

My question: to me, it makes sense that essentially we want the operator $T$ to be a *contraction*. To me, this seems to be the case whenever $\rho(T)<1$, i.e. the spectral radius is bounded by $1$. By Gelfand's formula, this condition is *weaker* than $\|T\|_{op}<1$. Are there any results on existence (and uniqueness, continuous dependence on initial conditions) under this condition on the spectral radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but it seems like a standard application of the Neumann series to me:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T:X \to X$ continuous. So in your special case $X=L^1[a,b]$ and $T$ the integral operator in your question.

Given $g \in X$ we are trying to find $f\in X$ that solves:
$$ g  = (I- T ) f .$$

Now if $ \rho(T) <1$, then the following series converges absolutely (in operator norm) by the root test (geometric series):
$$
(I-T)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n. 
$$

Therefore
$f = (I-T)^{-1}g $ is the unique solution to the problem and the solution depends continuously on the input $g$, since $(I-T)^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I have been focusing too much on the details of my particular problem instead of on the underlying structure..